# Trying to get the unescape function from Javascript recreated in C++

Tags: c++, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode HTML Entities in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082162/how-to-decode-html-entities-in-c)
>   [How can I decode HTML entities in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078520/how-can-i-decode-html-entities-in-c)

I didn't see anything good on this, which means this could be a good topic.

I have written a quick escapeHTML function in C++ which will escape stuff which is cool, but how would I unescape it with C++ as well?

It really is the idea of looking for a &, followed by a "lt;", "gt;", "quot;", "amp;" and return the relevant data.

Does anyone have a version they created?  If not I will create an efficient version of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode HTML Entities in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082162/how-to-decode-html-entities-in-c), related question [So we've got our HTML escape functions that really work in a C++ manner, how to do unescape?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976445/so-weve-got-our-html-escape-functions-that-really-work-in-a-c-manner-how-to)

Comment: Thank you for the link, im looking at it now.

Comment: just noticed. :)  Ill take a Look Sachleen

Comment: Note that JavaScript's [`window.unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.unescape) function is *not* for unescaping HTML.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is unrelated to JavaScript?

Comment: Couldn't you take a look at chromiums v8 engines source code?

Comment: i have some HTML code that will break my JSON object, so i am escaping it, and then when i unescape it, it seems to work.